# Default Action in SDN Controller

Tags: layer3, sdn, mininet

In legacy IPv4 networks there exists a default route concept for routers where a router does not need to know exact destination of IP packet.

Is there a default action concept for SDN switches? Let me explain my case with an example:

I will insert a tcp flow whose destination layer 4 port is 80. But at the same time I want to handle icmp flows and arp queries. For doing this I will insert a tcp flow in switch with a high priority and at the same time I want to add a best effort flow which handles all other conditions.

Thanks

Comment: "_In legacy IPv4 networks there exists a default route concept for routers where a router does not need to know exact destination of IP packet._" That is not correct; the router always needs to know the exact destination of a packet, which is the destination address in the packet header. If a router doesn't have a network/mask in its routing table that matches the destination address, the packet is dropped. The network/mask of `0.0.0.0/0` matches all destinations, and it is called the default route if it is installed in the routing table.

Comment: You are right I meant router does not need to be in same subnet with destination by "know" word

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a low priority flow entry that matches all frames.  The default behavior for unknown frames is to drop them.